# python 2.7 - login try

Tags: python, authentication

Here are simple login scripts.

I have  little bugs.

In a text file write:

```
name :test    
password :123321    
admin :0
```

I want to do:

```
if password and username exist then 
    #do code
else
    #do code
```

```
import os
import sys

print "Hello to login - login(username,password)"
login = 0
att = 1
while login == 0:

#Check if user login/exist

Log = raw_input("Enter username: ")
if os.path.isfile(Log + ".txt"):
    userfile = (Log+".txt")
    f = open(userfile,"r")
    Pass = raw_input("enter password: ")
    Lines = f.readlines()
    Password1 = Lines[1].split(":")
    Passwordl = Lines[1].strip()
    if Passwordl[10:] == Pass:
        login = 1
        break
elif att == 3:
    print "you try to log in more then 3 time, user locked"
    break
else:
    print "username not exist or pass wrong"
    att += 1


if login == 1:
    print "Welcome "
```

Comment: show us the problem

Comment: Problem is that the else is excute just in the first if, thats say if password wrong it return to loop

Comment: you should use a counter or something and also use a while loop. not a if else loop

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is indenting- you want to indent everything from Log= to be within the while loop

```
import os
import sys

print "Hello to login - login(username,password)"
login = 0
att = 1
while login == 0:

#Check if user login/exist

    Log = raw_input("Enter username: ")
    if os.path.isfile(Log + ".txt"):
        userfile = (Log+".txt")
        f = open(userfile,"r")
        Pass = raw_input("enter password: ")
        Lines = f.readlines()
        Password1 = Lines[1].split(":")
        Passwordl = Lines[1].strip()
        if Passwordl[10:] == Pass:
            login = 1
            break
    elif att == 3:
        print "you try to log in more then 3 time, user locked"
        break
    else:
        print "username not exist or pass wrong"
        att += 1
```